# BorutaPy selects different features in different iterations

Tags: python, feature-selection, importance, boruta

I came up to something strange. I know Boruta should select everything that is important.

I have a dataframe of 200 observations and 2000 features. if I shuffle the order of the features in the dataframe, Boruta (Random forrest classifier) will return different important features. I understand the random_state, but if different important features are selected I also get different prediction result which shouldn't happen - if everything important gets selected.

Also if I have 200 observations with first 1000 features Boruta selects a list of n-important features. But If I add another 1000 to the mix Boruta will select another set of features and the features from the first 1000 group won't be in them.

So why is Boruta always selecting different features if it should always select the best ones? How can best features change if you change the order of columns.

https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/boruta_py/issues/121